# How to have perl web crawler do 'breadth first' retrieval, like wget?

Tags: perl, web-crawler, wget

I have written a basic web crawler in `perl`.  How can I make it more sophisticated by having it do 
the retrieval in a 'breadth first' manner, like `wget` does?

This is from the [wget docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download):

> Recursive retrieval of HTTP and HTML/CSS content is breadth-first.
>   This means that Wget first downloads the requested document, then the
>   documents linked from that document, then the documents linked by
>   them, and so on. In other words, Wget first downloads the documents at
>   depth 1, then those at depth 2, and so on until the specified maximum
>   depth.

Any comments about my code would also be appreciated.

```
use feature 'say';
use WWW::Mechanize;
use List::MoreUtils 'any';

##############
# parameters #
##############
my $url = "https://www.crawler-test.com/"; # starting url
my $depth_level = 2; # depth level for crawling (level 1 will only look at links on the starting page)
my $filter = ".pdf"; # for multiple types use this format: ".pdf|.docx|.doc|.rtf"
my $wait = 2; # wait this number of seconds between http requests (be kind to the server)
my $domain = ""; # only crawl links with host ending in this string, leave blank if not required. For multiple domains, use this format: "domain1|domain2"
my $nocrawlagain = 1; # setting this to 1 will mean that the same link will not be crawled again, set to 0 to turn this off
##############


$domain = quotemeta($domain);
$domain =~ s/\\\|/|/g;

my @linkscrawled;

open LOG, ">mecherrors.log";
LOG->autoflush;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(stack_depth => 0, onerror => \&mecherror);

sub crawl {

    my $url = shift;
    my $filter = shift;
    my $depth = shift || 1;

    return if $depth > $depth_level;

    say "Crawling $url";
    $mech->get($url);
    sleep $wait;
    return unless ($mech->success and $mech->is_html);


    my @linkstocrawl;

    for $link ($mech->find_all_links(url_abs_regex => qr/^http/))  # only get http links (excludes things like mailto:)
    {

        next if $link->url =~ /#/;  # excludes URLs that are referring to an anchor

        # if the link matches the filter then download it
        if ($link->url =~ /($filter)$/)
        {
            my $urlfilename = ($link->URI->path_segments)[-1];
            next if -e $urlfilename;
            $mech->get($url); # go to base page
            sleep $wait;
            $mech->get($link->url);
            sleep $wait;
            my $filename = $mech->response->filename;
            next if -e $filename;
            $mech->save_content($filename);
            say "Saved $filename";

        } else {

            push @linkstocrawl, $link;

        }
    }

    for $link (@linkstocrawl)
    {
        next unless $link->url_abs->host =~ /($domain)$/;
        if ($nocrawlagain)
        {
            # skip if already crawled this link
            next if any { $_ eq $link->url_abs->abs } @alreadycrawled;
            push @alreadycrawled, $link->url_abs->abs;
        }
        crawl($link->url_abs->abs, $filter, $depth + 1);
    }

}


crawl($url, $filter);

sub mecherror {
    print LOG "[", $mech->uri, "] ", $mech->response->message, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do breadth-first, you need to take the `my @linkstocrawl` declaration out of `sub crawl` so that there's just one master to-do list rather than a separate list for each invocation of the crawling sub.

It will also be easier to do breadth-first if you make the code non-recursive, because recursion lends itself to depth-first more-or-less automatically.  (When you recursively call a sub to handle a section of the search space, that sub won't return until that section is completely finished, which isn't what you want for breadth-first.)

So the general structure you'd want is something like (not complete or tested code):

```
my @linkstocrawl = $starting_url;
my %linkscrawled; # hash instead of array for faster/easier lookups

while (my $url = shift @linkstocrawl) {
  next if exists $linkscrawled{$url}; # already saw it, so skip it
  $linkscrawled{$url}++;

  my $page = fetch($url);
  push @linkstocrawl, find_links_on($page);
  # you could also push the links onto @linkstocrawl one-by-one, depending on
  # whether you prefer to parse the page incrementally or grab them all at once

  # Do whatever else you want to do with $page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a depth-first search (DFS) and a breadth-first search (BFS) is quite simple:

- A DFS uses a to-do stack.

  ```
  my @todo = ...;
  while (@todo) {
     my $job = pop(@todo);
     push @todo, process($job);
  }
  ```
- A BFS uses a to-do queue.

  ```
  my @todo = ...;
  while (@todo) {
     my $job = shift(@todo);
     push @todo, process($job);
  }
  ```

Recursion is a technique that takes advantage of a stack of execution states. This is why a recursive search routine will perform a depth-first search. You will need to eliminate the recursive calls to `crawl`.

Each request requires two pieces of information: The URL to request, and the depth of the page. The elements of our to-do list will consist of these two-part task definitions.

Using the above for guidance, the following is the desired overall flow of the code:

```
my @todo = [ $starting_url, 0 ];
my %urls_seen = map { $_ => 1 } $start_url;

while (@todo) {
   my ($url, $depth) = @{ shift(@todo) };

   my $response = fetch($url);

   # Optionally do something with $response.

   my $linked_depth = $depth+1;
   if ($linked_depth <= $max_depth) {
      push @todo,
         map [ $_, $linked_depth ],
            grep !$urls_seen{$_}++,
               find_links($response);
   }

   # Optionally do something with $response.
}
```

By the way, you should prevent the UA from following redirects automatically (`requests_redirectable => []`) to avoid downloading a page you've previously downloaded.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to follow the redirections myself in the code?

Comment: Yes. You can copy the logic from LWP::UserAgent